# Name/number column name with a loop or similar

Tags: r

I want to add new columns to a existing data frame and I would like to increase the number/name of these columns.

E.g from

```
Apples Raspberries Bananas
```

I want to go to

```
Apples Raspberries Bananas Beta_0 Beta_1 Beta_2 Beta_3 Beta_..
```

Up to now I just have

```
for(i in 0:3){
  data.frame[ , "Beta_[(%d<- %d i)"] <- "NA" 
}
```

I guess it must work somehow but cannot figure out how, so I tried something different:

```
colnames(data.frame)<- paste("Beta", 0:3, sep="")
```

which worked in such a way that the first four column names were changed. But I need additional columns and the appropriate names.

Comment: perhaps `paste("Beta", 0:nrow(data.frame), sep="")` to label all columns in the same fashion, not sure what the "appropriate" names would be

Comment: @Nate Thanks, I guess I didn't explain it sufficiently. I do not want to change all column names but to add new columns with the name Beta_0, Beta_1, Beta_2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the built-in dataset mtcars:

```
mtcars[paste("Beta", 0:2, sep = "_")] <- NA
```

The column names in the resulting data.frame are:

```
names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"    "cyl"    "disp"   "hp"     "drat"   "wt"     "qsec"   "vs"     "am"    
#[10] "gear"   "carb"   "Beta_0" "Beta_1" "Beta_2"
```

All new columns have only NA-values.